# Regular expression of partial url

Tags: c#, regex, iis

I have the following:

```
https://www.example.com/my-suburl/sub-dept/xx-xxxx-xx-yyyyyy/
```

Im trying to find the 'yyyyy' in the url so far I have:

```
(.*)\/sub-dept\/(.*[^\/])\/([^\/]*)$
```

Which matches on:

```
https://www.example.com/my-suburl
```

and

```
xx-xxxx-xx-yyyyyy
```

However like i say I need the 'yyyyy' specific match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NON-C#-BASED SOLUTION**

If `xx` are numbers in the actual strings, just use

```
\d+(?=\/$)
```

Or else, use

```
[^-\/]*(?=\/?$)
```

See [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/dL4rD5/1) and [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/dL4rD5/2)

Note that in JS, there is no look-behind, thus,  if you must check if /sub-dept/ is in front of the substring you need, you will have to rely on *capturing group* mechanism:

```
\/sub-dept\/[^\/]*-([^-\/]*)\/?
```

See yet [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/dL4rD5/3)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Here is a regex you can use

```
(?<=/sub-dept/[^/]*-)[^/-]*(?=/$)
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%2fsub-dept%2f%5b%5e%2f%5d*-)%5b%5e%2f-%5d*(%3f%3d%2f%24)&i=https%3a%2f%2fwww.example.com%2fmy-suburl%2fsub-dept%2fxx-xxxx-xx-yyyyyy%2f)

The regex matches a substring that contains 0 or more characters other than a `/` or `-` that is...

- `(?<=/sub-dept/[^/]*-)` preceded with `/sub-dept/` followed by 1 or more characters other than `/` and then a hyphen
- `(?=/$)` - is followed by a `/` symbol right at the end of the string.

Or, there is a non-regex way: split the string by `/`, get the last part and split by `-`. Here is an example (without error/null checking for demo sake):

```
var result = text.Trim('/').Split('/').LastOrDefault().Split('-').LastOrDefault();
```

Comment: Please check this solution. Let me know if it works or there is anything unclear.

Comment: - the demo also highlights the hyphen - also the expression is  not liked by the javascript parsers.  The lookbehind isinvalid. It has to be used for both javascript and iis re-write rules essentially.  Sorry dont need c# anymore.  Cheers

Comment: You can actually discard the look-behind *unless* there are similar strings without `/sub-dept/` and the `yyyy` at the end. Are these numbers in actual strings? Then just use [`\d+(?=\/$)`](https://regex101.com/r/dL4rD5/1). Or else, use [`[^-\/]*(?=\/?$)`](https://regex101.com/r/dL4rD5/2). One more note: in JS, there is no look-behind, thus you will have to rely on capturing group mechanism: [`\/sub-dept\/[^\/]*-([^-\/]*)\/?`](https://regex101.com/r/dL4rD5/3) if you *must* check if `/sub-dept/` is in front of the substring you need.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting my answer if you found it helpful.